# Prove $(n^2)$ is $O(n^2 \log{n})$ by using Big-O definition

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

How does one go about proving the relationship using the big-O definition?

I get as far as:

$(n^2)$ is $O(n^2 \log{n}),\ n\geq k$

$(n^2) \leq C(n^2 \log{n}),\ n\geq k$

However dividing by $n^2$ leaves me in a position where

$1 \leq C(\log{n}),\ n\geq k$

which isn't true for all positive values of n as log(1) = 0

Comment: It's not supposed to be true for all positive values of $n$, just for $n$ sufficiently large (that is, for $k$ large enough).

Comment: The point of big O notation is to talk about the *eventual* behaviour of a function. Your statement doesn't need to be true for all values of $n$, just all $n \ge N$ for some $N$. Try taking $N=2$ and $C=1$.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. That clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{n^2}{n^2\log(n)} = \frac{1}{\log(n)}$ which tends to $0$, it must be bounded by some $C$ for all $n\ge K$. (Try using the definition of convergence of sequences to show this). Or in particular, for all $n\ge 5$, $1/\log(n) \le \frac{1}{\log(5)}\le 1.$